# Angular2 http get request results into 404

Tags: http, angular

Trying to run a simple http get call in Angular 2 + TypeScript
given on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

here: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html

```
private heroesUrl = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/575ed63f1100004f1b2992f4';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data)
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I also tried my local server url such as `http://localhost:5000/api`

But nothing works and the **console shows**

```
VM2510 hero.service.ts!transpiled:66 An error occurred Response {_body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}
```

*complete exception*

`EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
platform-browser.umd.js:962 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ platform-browser.umd.js:972ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3696(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8951schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6007SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:5996onError @ core.umd.js:6227onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6096ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:233_loop_1 @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:426
platform-browser.umd.js:962 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3698(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8951schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6007SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:5996onError @ core.umd.js:6227onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6096ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:233_loop_1 @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:426
platform-browser.umd.js:962 Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:538)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:523)
    at zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:571
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:356)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6066)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:355)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:256)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:474)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:426)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3699(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8951schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6007SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:5996onError @ core.umd.js:6227onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6096ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:233_loop_1 @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:426
zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Response {_body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…} ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Response {_body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}consoleError @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:461_loop_1 @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:426
zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object](…)`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS`?

Comment: I simply tried this on https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got to know from other forums and examples that we should use jsonp to access crossdomain rests.
e.g. http://plnkr.co/edit/0dFCzRdmBwcT99WR5Lbd?p=preview

@Component

```
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS}  from 'angular2/http';
...
..
 providers:[JSONP_PROVIDERS]
```

In Service:

```
import {Jsonp, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
```

Comment: What if you don't want to use jsonp? It is perhaps a CORS issue?