# Angular2 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost/WebApi2/api/hero

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise

I have tried the http Angular 2 and TypeScript example on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html it works.
https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview

Updated code to use external Web Api

```
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
// private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api
private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost/WebApi2/api/hero';  // URL to web api

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
   return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Now I want to update it to use an external Web Api2 and get the error below.

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost/WebApi2/api/hero"
>   An error occurred Object { _body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Object, type: null, url: "http://localhost/WebApi2/api/hero" }

I have looked at this solution but it does not work for me.
[Angular2 http get request results into 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794216/angular2-http-get-request-results-into-404)

Error on import

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { JSONP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
```

> Http/Http/node_modules/@angular/http/index"' has no exported member 'JSONP_PROVIDERS'.

Could anyone point me in the correct direction, example of calling Web Api2 from Angular2?

Comment: That resource doesn't exist on the server. So, either you're using the wrong URL, or it's a server issue, which has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: The Plunker link you provided doesn't contain any of your code. Update it to an absolute link

Comment: Does Angular 2 itself has Promise methods or you're trying to use ES6 (TypeScript ) Promise?

Comment: The resource does exist I have tested it in IIS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I personnaly fought with this for over two weeks before I landed on a post by @mp-loki -- [Angular 2 HTTP GET 404 Not Found for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923209/angular-2-http-get-404-not-found-for-url) -- here on stackoverflow: The credit therefore really goes to him (or her, to be safe).

On the Angular setup page (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html), you are greeted with this sentence: "*Install the Angular QuickStart seed for faster, more efficient development on your machine.*"

You probably followed the instructions on that setup page and your project is therefore based on the *Angular QuickStart Seed*.

There's nothing wrong with that, only that the tutorial given by Angular uses an **in-memory web api**, and that intercepts all requests to another web api, whether you make a direct call to the in-memory web api from your project code or not.

To make requests to a different web api, you therefore have to disconnect  from the in-memory web api. How? Just follow the steps below:

1. In your project root directory, expand **node_modules** and delete the `angular-in-memory-web-api` directory
2. Still in your project root directory, open the **package.json** file and remove the following line from the list of dependencies: `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",`
3. In the **src/app** directory, if the following files exit, or any files related to in-memory, delete them: `in-memory-data.service.ts`, `in-memory-data.service.js`, and `in-memory-data.service.js.map`
4. Open **src/app/app.module.ts** and remove the following from the list of imports: `import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';`, and `import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';`
5. Still in **src/app/app.module.ts**, remove this line of code from the @NgModule annotation: `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),`
6. At this stage you should be able to make requests to your web api, but most likely the object returned doesn't have a **`data`** property, so you remove it from your service file: Replace:

> ```
> getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
>    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
>                .toPromise()
>                .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
>                .catch(this.handleError);
> }
> ```

with

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
   return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json() as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mtchuente for all your help.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, vous venez de me sauvez-là !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, after some frustrating researches I solved the 404 error thanks to [this](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/issues/94). The order of imports matters.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: omg thank you! Had the exact same issue. They should really update the documentation.

Comment: Truly helpful indeed. Just using the backticks => ` instead of single quotes did the trick. Thanks a ton~